# How to export values from UserForm to new Excel-sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a UserForm from which I wan't to copy Three different values and put them in my new sheet together with an explanation in front of each value, but it isn't working, could somebody help me understand why?

```
Private Sub cmbExport_Click()

Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = "Export"

Export.Range("A1").Value = "Riskpremie"
Export.Range("A2").Value = "Teknisk premie"
Export.Range("A3").Value = "Slutpremie"

Export.Range("B1").Value = TxtRiskpremie.Value
Export.Range("B2").Value = TxtTeknpremie.Value
Export.Range("B3").Value = txtSlutpremie.Value

End Sub
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try using `Sheets("Export").Range("A1").Value` instead of `Export.Range..`.

Comment: should always say where error occurs and at which code line. You should use the `WorkSheets("Export").Range("A1......)` bla-bla

Answer (score 0, accepted):

our `Export` is undefined so it won't work:

```
Private Sub cmbExport_Click()
Dim Export as wWorksheet
Set Export = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
Export.Name = "Export"

Export.Range("A1").Value = "Riskpremie"
Export.Range("A2").Value = "Teknisk premie"
Export.Range("A3").Value = "Slutpremie"

Export.Range("B1").Value = TxtRiskpremie.Value
Export.Range("B2").Value = TxtTeknpremie.Value
Export.Range("B3").Value = txtSlutpremie.Value

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends where you `Sub` is. If its in a module, you have to reference the `FORM`. i.e.:

```
Dim oF as UserForm1
```

You can then reference the fields in the `FORM`:

```
Sheets("Export").Range("B1").Value = oF.TxtRiskpremie.Value
```